# Relative layout in XML file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code in my XML file:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/pic" />          
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phone_pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/phone_pic" />            
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want the `ImageView` and `EditText` field inside the `RelativeLayout` and the E`EditText` Field to the right of the `ImageView`. However, when i check the graphical layout, the `EditText` and `ImageView` are placed outside the `RelativeLayout` as well as the `LinearLayout`. What am I doing wrong and how to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you replace your `RelativeLayout` with horizontal `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />          
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone_pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />            
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you........

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf`

> Positions the left edge of this view to the right of the given anchor
>   view ID. Accommodates left margin of this view and right margin of
>   anchor view.

So try this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pic" />          
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone_pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_pic" />            
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

If you want an example to understand better, here is one for you. And there is still a source code so you can test. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pic" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/phone_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/phone_pic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. rogcg said try android:layout_toRightOf it will work. However you have to make certain changes in your Linear Layout attributes also. You have specified   android:layout_height="60dip"

which is causing the consecutive relative layout to be hidden. Make it to fill parent and set layout_toRightOf. It will work.

Also for the image view assign a src as follows
android:src="@drawable/someimage"

Thanks & Regards,
Rajamanickem.S

Answer (score -1):

change these line of code in your layout this is wrong

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/phone_pic" 
android:layout_alignRight="@id/pic"
```

write these below lines

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone_pic"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pic"
```

Comment: Lo, try again, you didn't change anything